# Co Browsing using Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I want to implement a silverlight based component for Co-Browsing.

Can you please help me get started?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any more requirements/guiding than "silverlight" and "co-browsing (web pages???)". Do you plan to have a server where clients can communicate between each other. What kind of actions should be possible? One client following the other? Annotations on screen? Pointing on each others screens? You need to be much more specific about what you want to do.

Comment: I just want an admin to share its browser with clients.

Comment: like they would share desktops via remote desktop or team viewer?

Comment: only browser. Something what http://www.livelook.com/ does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, first things first. I'm going to assume that you already figured out how to get commands from the "admin" to the "client". If this is not true, just let me know.

Second: this is an outrageously difficult thing to build

Third: here's a start ;-)

To use the default SL4 webbrowser component, you need to run your application out-of-browser with elevated trust. So you should set that up first.

In my test app, I added a webbrowser component and subscribed to the `LoadCompleted` event.

In your eventhandler you can use something like:

```
void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     //Pseudo code event to update clients
     OnAdminNavigated(e.Uri); 
}
```

Clientside you would use something like:

```
void adminNavigated(MyCustomNavigationEventArgs e)
{
  clientBrowser.Navigate(e.Uri);
}
```

Hope this helps.